# data analysis using SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database (SQLite) that has the following schema:

`Users(UserID, DateUsed, Device)`

This a database that has users that used a device on a certain date. I need to write a query that returns the number of users who used at least two different devices on at least two different days.

So for example:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| **UserID** | **DateUsed** | **Device** |
|    1034    |  01/01/2018  |   iPhone   |
|    1034    |  01/07/2018  |   Galaxy   |
|    1034    |  01/18/2018  |   iPhone   |
|    1082    |  01/19/2018  |   iPhone   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

The query would return a count of 1 because 1 user used at least two different phones on two different dates.

How would you go about writing this query?

I wrote the query to get the total amount of users so I can compare the answer to that number and that query was:

```
select count (distinct UserID) from Users
```

Comment: Have you tried anything that didn't work?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is it each device is used on two different days?  Is it two different days where exactly one of the devices was used?

Comment: We are just checking if a user used at least two different devices on different dates

Comment: so since user 1034 used an iphone on one day and a galaxy on another day, it would count as 1 since they used two different devices on two different days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following table and inserted the data you provided:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID INTEGER, 
    DateUsed VARCHAR, 
    Device VARCHAR
)

INSERT INTO Users (UserID, DateUsed, Device) VALUES (1034, '01/01/2018', 'iPhone');
INSERT INTO Users (UserID, DateUsed, Device) VALUES (1034, '01/07/2018', 'Galaxy');
INSERT INTO Users (UserID, DateUsed, Device) VALUES (1034, '01/18/2018', 'iPhone');
INSERT INTO Users (UserID, DateUsed, Device) VALUES (1082, '01/19/2018', 'iPhone');
```

This query returns the answer to your question:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT DateUsed || Device)
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY UserID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DateUsed || Device)>1
)
```

It's returning 1 by counting the user with ID 1034.
Note that I concatenated the DateUsed and Device in the subquery because you specifically asked users who used **2 devices on 2 different dates**.

If you want users who used at least **2 devices anytime**, you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT Device)
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY UserID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Device)>1
)
```

If you want users who used at least **2 devices on one day**, you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, DateUsed, COUNT(DISTINCT Device)
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY UserID, DateUsed
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Device)>1
)
```